# Pattern code to guess the textfile codepage in perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8, codepages, cp1251

Sorry for my noob's question, but I can't make the next script work.
It's a useful peace of code, but I did not find the similar working one in net.

```
use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;

open (my $fhr, "<", "$folder\\$_")
  or die "Could not open file '$folder\\$_' $!";
my $data = do { local $/; <$fhr> };
close $fhr;

# It is either cp1251 or utf-8.
my  $enc = guess_encoding ($data, qw/cp1251/ );
ref($enc) or die "Can't guess: ".$enc->name();
print "Encode = ".$enc->name()."\n";

my $decoded = decode ($enc, $data);
```

The console output follows:

```
utf8 "\xCE" does not map to Unicode at double_fin.pl line 167, <$fhr> chunk 1.
Encode = utf8
Cannot decode string with wide characters at C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/Encode.pm line 176.
```

What do I do wrong?
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: It seems that the first message comes when perl tries to decode the content of the file `double_fin.pl` as UTF-8? Maybe you should try read the file using the PerlIO layer `:raw` instead of using the `:utf8` layer?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, open (my $fhr, "<:raw", "$folder\\$_") ... It seems, it's working: no warnings, no errors. Thank you.

Comment: Great! You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message

```
utf8 "\xCE" does not map to Unicode at double_fin.pl line 167, <$fhr> chunk 1
```

comes when `perl` tries to decode the content of the file `double_fin.pl` as UTF-8. But the file contains invalid UTF-8, so you need to read in the file using the PerlIO layer `:raw` instead of using the `:encoding(utf8)` layer.

See also http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html.